# Where can I find spatial data for UK administrative boundaries?

Tags: shapefile, data, united-kingdom, format

I am specifically looking for UK local authorities, wards, postcodes in shp file format.

Comment: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html and https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html perhaps?

Comment: general information: an ESRI "shapefile" is actually composed of the three file types that you listed.  Often people refer to wanting a .shp file or exporting to a .shp format, but really they are referring to a set of files, .shp, .shx and .dbf (sometimes there are more, like .prj, etc) which are read by GIS software as a "shapefile".  A .lyr file is a set of styling information that must reference a shapefile or an online map service.

Answer (score 2):

[OSGeo has a Public Geodata for the UK list](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Public_Geodata_for_the_UK). The second link is for boundary data.

You may also want to look at [data.gov.uk Boundary-Line data](http://data.gov.uk/dataset/boundary-line)

Comment: Thanks for all your links. Was not aware of OSgeo- which looks like a great resource.

Comment: Why use OSgeo when you can download a zipped set of shp files (or csv in the case of codeopint) directly from the data supplier, as in the links I posted above?

Comment: John, you should add your OS comment as an answer - I'd up-vote it.